# useCallback not changing variable value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, callback, foxglove-studio

I am using ReactJS along side Foxglove Studio to create a custom panel with a slider on it. I have created the slider, but when I attach a callback to the `onChange` element of the slider the slider remains static and doesn't allow me to move it
[image: Static slider]

```js
let LEDValue: number | number[] = 0;

const sliderOnChange = useCallback(
  (_event: Event, value: number | number[]) => {
    if (value !== LEDValue) {
      value = LEDValue;
    }
  },
  [LEDValue],
);

const min = 0;
const max = 254;
const step = 1;
const marks = [
  { value: min, label: String(min) },
  { value: max, label: String(max) },
];

return (
  <div style={{ padding: "1rem" }}>
    <h2>{LEDValue}</h2>
    <Slider
      min={min}
      max={max}
      step={step}
      marks={marks}
      value={typeof LEDValue === "number" ? LEDValue : 0}
      onChange={sliderOnChange}
    />
  </div>
);
```

No errors when I build it, I just can't drag the slider and values don't update. Am I missing something?

Comment: `value = LEDValue;` This is just changing a local variable. It's not going to rerender the component. Did you intend to have `LEDValue` be a react state, and set that state?

Comment: Yes, I'll do some research. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `useState` to store Led value
also the logic on function `sliderOnChange` doesn't seem correct

```
const [ LEDValue, setLEDValue ] = useState(Number);

const sliderOnChange = useCallback(
   (_event: Event, value: number | number[]) => {
      // If using useState
      setLedValue(Number(value));
   },
   [LEDValue],
);
```

Comment: You can't `setLedValue(value)` since it is of type `number | number[]` - but if you `setLedValue(Number(value))` it works. You also do not need to assign `LEDValue = value`. Thank you for your answer - I have added an edit to queue.